# Block signal from propagating to the inferior when using ptrace

Tags: gdb, trace, ptrace

I had put a simple trap instruction to simulate a breakpoint on the inferior, but when this instruction is reached I got a CLD_KILLED instead of CLD_SIGTRAP, like the one below.

--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=12668, si_uid=10157, si_status=SIGTRAP, si_utime=2692, si_stime=875}

It seems that gdb is able to prevent SIGTRAP to kill the inferior by using the command "handle SIGSTOP nopass".

How can I do it in C?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page,
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=siginfo&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.1-RELEASE

```
 SIGCHLD
si_pid       child process ID
si_status    exit value or signal; if si_code is equal to
             CLD_EXITED, then it is equal to the exit
             value of the child process, otherwise, it is
             equal to a signal that caused the child
             process to change state.
```

In your case `si_code=CLD_KILLED` so the clause *`si_status` [...] is equal to a signal that caused the child to change state.*

Thus `si_status=SIGTRAP` is the information you're looking for.

If you had `ptrace` your child you would have gotten a `SIGTRAP` instead.

Comment: I discovered later that I had to attach to the thread of the process that I was debugging, what's why got si_code=CLD_KILLED. I was only attaching the main process.